# Selectively replacing text with HTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

How can I replace text on a page using jQuery without replacing tags and text within tags such as: `<a>,<input>,<button>,<textarea>,<input>,<select>`.

For example, here is the HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello, this is a test replacing {REPLACE_ME} with <b>{REPLACED}</b>.
    <br/><br/>
    I want {REPLACE_ME} and {REPLACE_ME} to be <b>{REPLACED}</b>, however I don't want this <a href="#">{REPLACE_ME}</a> to become <a href="#">{REPLACED}</a>.
    Same with <textarea>{REPLACE_ME}</textarea>, it shouldn't change.
    <br/><br/>
</body>
```

I have this jQuery to replace the text

```
var replaced = $("body").html().replace(/{REPLACE_ME}/gi,'<b>{REPLACED}</b>');
 $("body").html(replaced);
```

Here it is on JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/E8ZPY/

Comment: You missed to add jQuery lib see it works without replacing tags http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/E8ZPY/3/

Comment: it just working fine, what is th problem

Comment: FYI, you list `input` twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('body, body *:not(a,button,textarea,option)').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).each(function() {
    var escaped = $('<div></div>').text($(this).text()).html();
    $(this).replaceWith(escaped.replace(/\{REPLACE_ME\}/gi,'<b>{REPLACED}</b>'));
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E8ZPY/21/)

(I didn't need to include `input`, and I used `option` instead of `select`, since `option` is the one with text nodes for children.)

Answer (score 0):

first add jquery file

apply "\" in regex pattern for special character

```
var replaced = $("body").html().replace(/\{REPLACE_ME\}/gi,'<b>{REPLACED}</b>');
                             // see here^^^__________^^^^    

$("body").html(replaced);
```

**[see updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E8ZPY/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var replaced = $("body").html().replace(/[^>]{REPLACE_ME}[^<]*/gi, '<b>{REPLACED}</b>');
$("body").html(replaced);
```

Comment: Looks like it's replacing `{REPLACE_ME}` not in tags with `<b>{REPLACED}</b>` to me...